# My HttpHandler doesn't want to create directory on a network

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, httphandler

I use this simple line of code inside my HttpHandler:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\srv-001\dev\folderToCreate\");
```

I receive an **UnauthoridezAccessException** telling me that the access to the path is denied.

From here, I create a little Dos application in C# doing the same thing and I was able to create the folder. So, I thought that it might be that IIS is running on a different user than myself. I went to IIS and changed the Application pool to a Custom user, myself. But, unfortunately, I got the same exception.

I have try to create a Share folder on my computer and I can create directory. Also, when debugging I can see that System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity have its AuthenticationType to "", IsAuthenticated to false and name to "".

So, with all those tests I can conclude that the HttpHandler that receive the file cannot create a directory because of some security access.

How can I grand access to my HttpHandler to be able to create a directory (and files) to a network folder?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://weblogs.asp.net/drnetjes/archive/2005/06/06/410508.aspx

Comment: changing the identity under which the app pool runs should have done it.  maybe it's possible that you didn't change the right app pool.  i'd doublecheck the web application in question is in fact running in the app pool you think it is.  sounds like i'm stating the obvious, but usually these kinds of things happen when you overlook something obvious.  possible you looked at the app pool for the website and the application is running under a different app pool or something like that.  also, with multiple machines at work, i'd doublecheck that you changed iis on the right machine.

Comment: I have created a web.config in the HttpHandler directory with the two lines for impersonate and nothing changed.

Comment: It's the good one because when I hit ctrl+alt+del I can see my user name running w3wp.exe. In IIS I can see ASP.NET 4.0 (the one for my website) is using Integrated with my identity. I have also changed the DefaultAppPool... just in case...

Comment: I have created a new Web Site and it does work if it doesn't goes through the httphandler...

Answer (score 0):

actually, i thought of one other thing to check.  not only is there the app pool identity, but there is also an identity associated with anonymous authentication.  if you are on iis 7/7.5, you should be able to see the authentication icon for the web application and doubleclick that.  selecting anonymous authentication and then clicking edit will reveal a dialog that gives you the option of specifying a user or the app pool user.  i bet if you choose app pool user, that will fix it.

if you are on iis 6, i don't recall as clearly, but i'll give it a shot.  don't have iis 6 in front of me to verify, but i remember there being an anonymous access button you can click that would bring up a dialog where you could specify the user.  don't think you had the option there of using the app pool identity and had to specify the account explicitly.